# Argument types in functions versus in arrow functions in ES6

Tags: function

I have been looking into the implementation of ES6's Set objects and how an array with duplicates is collapsed to a set.

I have found this [performance comparison](https://jsperf.com/js-unique-set), which in and of itself is interesting. Then I wanted to write a shorter version of brettz9's code which goes:

```html
// https://gist.github.com/brettz9/6137753

function set (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (a, val) {
    if (a.indexOf(val) === -1) {
        a.push(val);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
}

var l = [
   { date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
   { date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
   { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];

var s = set(l);
```

Problem I stumble on is I could not figure out by looking into arrow functions' documentation, why the following code does not work:

```html
function set(a){a.reduce((s,o) => s.indexOf(o) === -1 ? s.push(o) : s);};
var s = set(l);
```

This returns a type error (which most likely is because the runtime can't figure out that s is an Array at the first iteration of the reduce function:

> TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function

I don't get how the code in the above snippet manages not to raise this type error since at the first iteration of the reduce function, there's no declaration or type "auto-cast" that says that `a` is an Array (and therefore has an indexOf function defined).

Comment: Are you getting any TypeErrors?

Comment: Yes : TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function. My guess is that the runtime can't figure out that s is an Array on the first iteration of the reduce function (which iterates on an Array from left to right). Although this problem does not arise in the code as implemented in the snippet above by brettz9.

Comment: I also have tried this form with no success: 
                                                             
`function set(a){a.reduce((s,o) => s.indexOf(o) > -1 ? s : s.push(o));}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.push` modifies the array in-place and returns the new length of the array. This means that once your ternary hits that branch, your accumulator object turns into a number instead. Try using `Array.concat` instead to merge two arrays and return a new array. Additionally, your arrow function version is missing an initial value for accumulator. If you don't provide an initial value, the first call to your callback is called with the first and second value from the array.

Try this instead:

```
function set(a){ return a.reduce((s,o) => s.indexOf(o) === -1 ? s.concat([o]) : s, []);};
var s = set(l);
```

Comment: Edited to include missing initial value for the accumulator.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought push returned an array. Thanks!

Comment: Ok about the first and second value of the array. But my interrogation is more on how does the runtime know that the function indexOf can be called on the object s (which is a free variable scoped to my arrow function) at first? I mean, s should be empty or null at first, right?

Comment: In this particular arrow function, ’s’ would be just like ’a’ in your first example - that is, the name of an argument. Array.prototype.reduce calls your arrow function in a predictable manner, passing it parameters that should not be null or undefined (unless the array itself contains null values). Knowing which properties an object has is a matter of traversing up the prototype chain of said object, looking up the property until no more prototypes can be found.